# Event handling of an loaded assembly at run-time

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, event-handling

Here is the scenario that I am trying to learn from which:

- There is DLL file raising an event sometimes.
- The DLL file cannot be added to references in source code, but it is available on disk, and the program can reach it at run-time.
- I loaded DLL files as an assembly for runtime.
- I am trying to subscribe to the event from the DLL (I know the signature and parameter formats), and handle them in my program.

The Assembly is a simple Dll with a method that adds its two arguments and raises an event with a custom argument including the result of the sum operation. Here is the the code for the DLL:

```
namespace Dll1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int c = 0;

        public void add(int a, int b)
        {
            c =  a + b;
            if (Added !=null)
                Added(this, new AddArgs(c));
        }

        public delegate void AddHandler(object sender, AddArgs e);

        public event AddHandler Added;

    }

    public class AddArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private int intResult;

        public AddArgs(int _Value) 
        {
            intResult = _Value;
        }

        public int Result
        {
            get { return intResult; }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in my program I loaded that DLL using Assembly.LoadFile. I have another class in my program called *EventProcessor* that contains an event handler to process events from the loaded assembly:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Type[] parmTypes;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Projects\Dll1.Dll");
            Type typ = asm.GetType("DLL1.Class1", true, true);

            var method = typ.GetMethod("add");
            EventInfo eInfo = typ.GetEvents()[0];
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typ);

            EventProcessor evProc = new EventProcessor();
            Type myTypeObj = evProc.GetType();
            MethodInfo myMethodInfo = myTypeObj.GetMethod("myEventHandler");

            Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(myTypeObj, myMethodInfo, true); // Error!
            eInfo.AddEventHandler(obj, d);

            method.Invoke(obj, new object[] { 1, 0 });
        }
    }
}
```

But, when run the program I get an error message "Type must derive from Delegate.
Parameter name: type". What I'm doing wrong here? Or is there any better way to handle this scenario? I also added my event handler class at the end, if it helps.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class EventProcessor
    {
        public void myEventHandler(object sender, AddArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event Received.");
        }
    }

    public class AddArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private int intResult;

        public AddArgs(int _Value)
        {
            intResult = _Value;
        }

        public int Result
        {
            get { return intResult; }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that ConsoleApplication1 doesn't have a reference to Dll1.  Even though you structured your `AddArgs` in both assemblies the same, they are still a different type and can't be used interchangeably.

The solution for this is to use a type that is known to both assemblies `ConsoleApplication1` and `Dll1`.  Both assemblies must use the same type.

You were also using the override of the `CreateDelegate` method that is used for static event methods.  Since you are trying to hook up an instance method, you must provide the target as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and revising the code. The reason I created a custom event argument was that I believe the type in generic EventHandler must be a TEventArg and cannot be the "int" type. Actually with EventHandler<int> I got an error: *The type 'int' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEventArgs' in the generic type or method 'System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>'. There is no boxing conversion from 'int' to 'System.EventArgs'.*